# How to convert AND normalize audio with VLC command line?

Tags: audio, wav, vlc, libvlc

I've figured out the CLI command to convert audio. I know VLC has volume normalization capabilities (see "normvol" filter). My question is: how can I normalize the volume of the input file and save that normalization into the converted output file?

Or does normalization only work with playback?

Comment: Please show your current CLI attempts

Comment: Try doing it in VLC with logs enabled so you can see which parameters are used